# Modal view in Angular Kendo mobile

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am experimenting with Angular Kendo mobile.
I want to build a modal view just like a popup window with option buttons.

I see Kendo UI provides modal view as:

```
<div data-role="modalview" id="my-modal" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
  Hello!
</div>
```

But what about using it on mobile using angular Kendo.
Is their any modal view provided by Angular Kendo for mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kendo Mobile ModalView](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/ui/modalview) does exactly what you are looking for.

```
<div id="modalview-photo" k-modal="false" kendo-mobile-modal-view="modal" use-native-scrolling="true" style="width: 99vw; height:99vh; background-color:white;">
     <kendo-mobile-header>
            <kendo-mobile-nav-bar>

            </kendo-mobile-nav-bar>
    </kendo-mobile-header>
    <div style="padding: 5px;">
        <label>title</label>
        <input id="photo-title" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Opens like that:

```
$("#modalview-photo").data().kendoMobileModalView.open();
```

Comment: Thanks for details, but I am looking for Kendo mobile solution. `data-role='modalview'` is Kendo UI component, and I am looking for Kendo mobile component. When I embed modal view inside `</kendo-mobile-view> </kendo-mobile-view>` then it does not work. I need a example of using `kendo-mobile-modal-view`

Comment: edited my answer, this code is from a project i work on with kendo mobile

Comment: Thanks for update. But as per the Kendo using kendo-window on mobile is not suggested and not recommended. I am building project using Angular Kendo mobile and not Kendo UI. kendo-window is Kendo UI component so I can't use it in my mobile app. have use used "kendo-mobile-modal-view".

Comment: @A_user so `kendo-mobile-modal-view` worked for you?

Comment: No I see one example of using it at https://github.com/kendo-labs/angular-kendo/blob/master/doc/mobile/MobileModalView.html but it is not working for me.

Comment: then the problem is in your project, maybe paste more code

Comment: Oh! I tested your updated code and it does work perfectly. only thing how can I change "$("#modalview-photo").data().kendoMobileModalView.open();" jQuery part to AngularJS one as my app is in AngularJS. Also when I click outside of the modal then it disappears how to restrict it and close it on button click. Thanks for help and sample code.

Comment: @A_user perfect mate! well just change `k-modal="false" ` to `k-modal="true" ` to restrict it from closing when clicking outside

Comment: also try `angular.element('#modalview-photo').data().kendoMobileModalView.open();` for opening, tell me if it worked

Comment: Thanks yes it does work. But it is not documented anywhere how to find it out? Also is the correct way of doing it in Angular?

Comment: @A_user yes mate you are correct Kendo has a real problem with documentation, everything i told you i had to find them alone. If someone from kendo is watching please fix your documentation!